# In 2-3 player Citadels, can your second character build a 9th district?

Tags: citadels

In Citadels, if a player builds his 8th building we finish the round with the remaining roles and the game ends.

In 2-3 players rules, I may build the 8th district with my first character. When comes the second character's turn, can I build an additional district?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Page 8 of the [rulebook](http://desktopgames.com.ua/games/3/citadelsrules.pdf) says (regarding 2-3 player games):

> The game is played normally, except that each player will have two
>   turns during each round (one turn for each character). Players do not
>   have to separate their gold or their districts between their
>   characters, as they still only have one city.

Page 7 of the rulebook says (regarding Game End):

> When a player builds his eighth district, the game ends after the
>   current round is completed. At the end of the game, each player
>   receives points for all of the following...

The rules do not say that you cannot build a 9th district with your 2nd character. It simply states that once the 8th district is built, the current round will be the last round. So each player gets two turns during each round, and you have to finish all of the turns for the final round. **Yes, you may build an additional district.**

Comment: I think you're right. I actually realized the architect could do the same, building up to 3 districts if he wants at the last round. There's no rule preventing him from doing so either. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Oh, great catch! I didn't even think of that! Enjoy!!

Comment: Yes. So your first character could build the 8th district, then if Architect was the second character they could build districts 9,10,11 (if you had the money or they were cheap, or with the help of some purple rules-modifying districts)

Comment: Page 7 of my physical rulebook also says *"Note: Players **may** build more than eight districts in their city if they have the means to do so"*